# Rails 4 form to set has_many through additional column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have a has_many association between Items and their Components through a table called ComponentItems. ComponentItems contains a column `quantity` in addition to `item_id` and `component_id`. How is it possible to add a number_field to my form that shows the quantity of each `component` required for an `item`? The form must contain a number_field for each Item in the database, even if no relationship exists (i.e. `@item.component_ids.empty? == true`).

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :components, through: :component_items
  has_many :component_items
end

class Component < Item
  has_many :items, through: :component_items
  has_many :component_items
end

class ComponentItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :component
end
```

I believe I've tried every permutation of model, controller and form_builder possible, except the correct one.

In response to the answer below, here's a form that shows a checkbox and the item code for component items that make up one particular item;

```
<%= form_for [@item] do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :component_items, Item.active.where.not(sku: @item.sku).sort_by{|n| n.sku}, :id, :sku do |b| %>
    <%= b.check_box %> <%= b.label %><br/>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So, ideally I'd replace the check_box with a number_field for quantity. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems what I wanted is not so straightforward after all. In the end I opted for using some jQuery for adding extra Components to Items via a separate form. Trying to add/remove components and adjust the quantities was beyond me, so choosing to use separate forms for each user action seemed simpler. It may not be the most user-friendly way of working but it's the best I have.

To edit the quantities I did the following;

```
        <% @item.component_items.each do |x| %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag "item[component_items_attributes][][id]", x.id%>
            <%= label_tag x.component.sku, x.component.sku.upcase, :class=>"col-md-3 control-label" %>
            <%= number_field_tag "item[component_items_attributes][][quantity]", x.quantity, :class=>"col-md-5"%>
        <%end %>
```

and ensured the Item model accepted nested attributes for `component_items`. Finally, add the nested params array for multiple `component_items` to items_controller.rb...

```
def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(
      :component_items_attributes =>[:component_id, :item_id, :quantity, :id]
    )
  end
```

Note I didn't use `fields_for` which seemed to generate an extra `component_items_attributes` array that didn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@item.components.to_a.sum(&:quantity)
```

This will throw an error if quantity on some component is nil, so you may try like this to avoid errors:

```
@item.components.to_a.map(&:quantity).compact.sum
```

UPDATE

```
<% @item.component_items.each do |component_item| %>
  <%= form_for(component_item) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :quantity, 'Quantity' %><br />
      <%= f.number_field :quantity %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `i.component_items.to_a.map(&:quantity)` will give an array of quantities for each of the component items, but does not help with the form generation. I've added an example to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood what do you exactly want, you want field that will show quantity number for every component from item.components, am I right?

Comment: Nearly. It must show quantity for every item. For components this will be at least 1, for other items it should be 0.

Comment: Do you need to just display this data? Using form doesn't seem to be right way for doing what you want.

Comment: No. The number_field will be used to edit quantity. Quantities >1 indicate a relationship between Item and Component.

Comment: But a component does not have a quantity, it is on the join table only. `undefined method 'quantity' for #<Component:0x007ffaeae11b20>`

Comment: I don't think you understand my wording of the question properly. Let me reiterate that the quantity field should be shown for *each* Item, not just components. Your response does not update the quantities and shows the Components + the original Item. So an Item with 5 Components will have 6 quantities above.

Comment: Sorry, this is best I can do.

Comment: Thanks for trying.